# How to pass aws credential keys to local docker container

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am running a **local docker containers on MAC** and want to pass my aws credentials **keys** from `~/.aws/credential` files to local **docker container**, so that it can access S3 buckets.

*I am using aws sdk for php and javascript.*

I am using *docker files* to fire up the docker containers. 
What is the best way to send my aws credential to docker container app so that it can access aws services?

Comment: The best way I found is to use roles on the aws resources you are consuming ... in this situation you do not need to worry about passing aws credentials to docker running in ECS containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass them as ENV variables when running `docker-compose run`

something like `docker-compose run -e AWS_VAR1=CREDENTIAL web python console.py`

See an example here in the documentation https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-envfile-configuration-option